# TypeError: undefined is not an object - when evaluating an array with forEach

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I am making a search bar, and I'm having a weird error that has not been solved by numerous other posts of the same error. I have an array, and I am using `forEach` to log to the console depending on the `index` of the array. However, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'sites[index].indexOf')
```

My code is as follows:

```
var sites = ["Website 1", "Website 2", "Youtube Test Page", "Go to google", "testing for foreward slashes", "MORE!!! :)", "beachballs", "test2", "Good Luck"];

function search() {
    var input = $("#searchBar")[0].value;
    sites.forEach(function(index) {
        console.log(input);
        if (sites[index].indexOf(input) != -1) {
            console.log("yay");
        }
    })
}
```

And here is my search bar:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search the web" id="searchBar" onkeyup="search()"/>
```

I have done a lot of research to no avail, so I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sites` is an *array*, not a jQuery collection, so when you call `forEach` on it, the first argument to the callback is the *item being iterated over*, not the index. Change to:

```
sites.forEach(function(site) {
    console.log(site);
    if (site.indexOf(input) != -1) {
        console.log("yay");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sites = ["Website 1", "Website 2", "Youtube Test Page", "Go to google", "testing for foreward slashes", "MORE!!! :)", "beachballs", "test2", "Good Luck"];

function search() {
    var input = $("#searchBar")[0].value;
    sites.forEach(function(value,index) {
        console.log(input);
        if (sites[index].indexOf(input) != -1) {
            console.log("yay");
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: use `function(value,index)` instead `function(index)`  and your `index` value will be as expected

Answer (score 1):

Array.forEach callback has 3 parameters.

> callback is invoked with three arguments:
>
> the **element value**
>
> the **element index**
>
> the **array being traversed**

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    //your iterator
});
```

as for your case you only need the first parameter `currentValue`.

Read more [Array.prototype.forEach() - Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)